# NSTimeInterval showing 0

Tags: objective-c, nstimeinterval

When tracking time since a date using NSTimeInterval, it shows 0.000000 in the NSLog. Here is my Time Interval:

```
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [intialtime timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

Here is how I log the data:

```
NSLog(@"%f",timeInterval);
```

What am I missing? Also, I want the time interval to show minutes since the date. Would I need to change anything to make this happen?

Comment: Is `initialTime` `nil`?

Comment: @rmaddy InitialTime seems to be fine. It shows the proper date in the log.

Comment: The code you show should work. You need to provide more context. Show the whole methods where you have those code bits, and also where you instantiate initialTime, and how you declare it.

Comment: `initialTime` may show the proper date, but what does `initialtime` show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Panic, try this.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
formatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy";

NSDate *intialTime= [formatter dateFromString:@"12/11/2005"];

NSDate *presentDate = [NSDate date];

NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [presentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:intialTime];

int seconds = (int)ceil(timeInterval);
int mins = seconds / 60;

NSLog(@"Time interval in Mins:%d",mins);
```